# Working gnu-screen alternative for WSL-minecraftserver

Tags: 18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I want to launch my minecraft server on SSH on WSL (Ubuntu 18.04) on Windows.

The way I plan to do it with a phone or something: Connect to vpn, then ssh into windows, then type wsl (works fine), and finally open a session (for example screen) and launch the script for the minecraft server in there.

The problem is, when I finally get into launching the script and detaching the screen and close the ssh connection, the screen will close after some time automatically. WSL says it was terminated. I dont know what to do.

I should also add that the script should run permanently. The mc server is running on java and constantly gives output. So I want it to be available all the time.

Comment: Are you asking how to use `screen`? Or are you asking for some kind of mentoring? The question does not seem clear.

Comment: I was asking for an alternative > title. Someone told my about linuxgsm.com and this solved everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

linuxgsm.com is a Server manager that is also available for minecraft, it uses tmux and is a perfect alternative with many other features.